# r left_join exclude columns to join

Tags: r, join, merge, left-join, tidyverse

I have a double repeated measures dataset (i.e., a participant is measured 3 times per session, and repeats session 2 times). Some of my data is preliminary demographic data that is only measured once (e.g., surveys) while the others are all repeated. A toy dataset is shown below:

Session 1:
[image: Session 1]

Session 2:
[image]

Survey Q1-Q5 are all the same, as they were preliminary measurements. The measurements are, however, different.

I've been able to join these 2 datasets by:

```
join <- left_join(Session1,Session2, by = "ID")
```

However, I want to exclude any of the preliminary surveys from session 2 so that only that info from session 1 is brought over to the new dataframe. The above line of code does not achieve that.

How might I be able to go about doing this?

Thanks!

Comment: If I understand correctly, can you just exclude these columns from `Session2` before merging? So: `join <- left_join(Session1, select(Session2, -Survey_Q1, -Survey_Q2, -Survey_Q3, -Survey_Q4, -Survey_Q5), by = "ID)`

Comment: That makes sense. I was hoping for some magical code solution. But IG I got too far into it without thinking! Thanks!

Comment: If there is something more complex that you need to achieve programatically I would be happy to help out, but this seems like the simplest way to do it for this use case!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just exclude the columns that you don't want. `join <- left_join(Session1,Session2[,-c(2:6)], by = "ID")` or `join <- left_join(Session1,Session2[,-c("Survey_Q1","Survey_Q2","Survey_Q3","Survey_Q4","Survey_Q5")], by = "ID")`